# Revert ng-model value in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to revert the model value when displaying it?

My controller has this property:

```
this.config = {client: false, name: true};
```

And I want to use the values like this:

```
<label>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.config.client"> Client
</label>

<div ng-hide="ctrl.config.client">Client</div>
```

I'd like to show the input checked when the config.client value is false. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you expand your example?  I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you want to change the checked state of an input type="radio" or "checkbox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If you want to check a checkbox, and you use `$scope` you can use `ng-true-value="false"` and `ng-false-value="true"` to revert the default values. This works only, if you use `$scope` instead of `this`! Here is an example:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="config.client" ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true">
  </label>

  <div ng-hide="config.client">Client</div>
  </div>
<script>
  angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.config = {client: false, name: true};
  });
</script>
</body>
```

And the plunker to try it: http://plnkr.co/edit/vRIZMb2CpDQAKHu91yhN?p=preview

Comment: But that blocked the hability to unchek it, I don't know why!

Comment: You're right, I've updated my post, please try it again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think you want [ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

And then negate it. So something like:

```
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="!ctrl.config.client" ng-model="ctrl.config.client"> Client
</label>
```

I am assuming you want a checkbox although it isn't clear from your example.

Comment: this creates a weird behaviour, you have to click twice to change state, or something like that.